# When are new tags a good edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I try to review as many suggested edits as I can and find that quite a few of them (sometimes even the majority) are simply the addition of a tag to the question.
Up to now I almost automatically mark these edits as `too minor`, but I've started wondering if this is the right way to go about it.

If so many of these suggested edits are like this, maybe that's what the users feel is needed to improve the posts? Is there a good way to differentiate between an added tag that is useful and a simple attempt to gain another edit?

Comment: My 2 cents... If you can't tell if the tag is necessary then you should skip

Comment: Of course, if a tag is definately needed (e.g. code language that wasn't tagged) then obviously it could be a good edit (even though it's still very minor).  
But if the tag is relevant but not so important and more edits could have been made to the post.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same criteria for approving a suggested tag edit as you would for making a normal tag edit.

In particular, approve edits that

1. Remove unnecessary, useless, meta or ambiguous tags (the kind that people are always asking to be burninated here on meta),
2. Improve the clarity of the question's subject matter (such as version-specific tags, if they apply),
3. Add a programming language, if it applies, and
4. Uses more specific and less ambiguous tags (such as [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) instead of [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc)).

Answer (score 1):

One rule of thumb that can reduce this problem is to look the at the time the question was asked.

Many of them are 5 or 10 minutes old, so it is ok to approve even if it is a minor suggestion, because the question being edited will still be in the active page. Therefore, it will not occupy the place of a question with a new answer, as if it was an old thread.

Another issue is, you can try to improve such editions. If the suggesting editor missed some improvements, write in the Edit Summary box what you have added, so he/she can learn from you and improve in the next suggestions. Problem very reduced!

Now, if it is an old thread, then the edit needs to be really substantial to be approved. A tag addition really needs to address a question that would be very difficult to search without that tag. It helps to pass the edition, in such cases, if the question does not have an answer.